# Ubuntu 18.04 touchpad not fully working after wake from suspend

Tags: 18.04, suspend, touchpad

When the laptop (Dell Vostro 15) wakes from suspend the mouse cursor can be moved with the touchpad at the login/lock screen, but once back in to the session does not move it.  At this point plugging in an external USB mouse works fine.  The touchpad works after a reboot, until suspending.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Reloading the touchpad / mouse driver after resuming from suspend works in most cases.

Run `sudo -H gedit /lib/systemd/system-sleep/touchpad`

Copy and paste in these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 == post ]]; then
    modprobe -r psmouse
    modprobe psmouse
fi
```

Save the file and exit.

Now make it a program by setting the execution bit:

```
chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/touchpad
```

You will need to reboot for changes to take effect.

Comment: This didn't help (I'd actually tried before manually rmmod and modprobing psmouse). But now, after another restart, it is working again. I believe some update was installed as well, so perhaps some transient kernel issue that was fixed?

Comment: This issue went away after an update. Not sure of its actual cause.

Comment: I should have put into the answer a reboot may be necessary for changes to take effect but I didn't fully research that part of the answer. Let me know if it is still broken after next suspend. Thanks.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. Ubuntu 18.04 with "SYNA8004:00 06CB:CD8B Touchpad", Lenovo X1 Carbon Gen 7. I get snappy touchpad behavior after resuming from hibernation.

Comment: @SaTa You need to reboot for changes to take effect. Also hibernation often brings a host of new problems not found with suspend/resume.

Comment: Thanks. The issue goes away if I do a reboot. Running `modprobe -r psmouse` and then `modprobe psmouse` from the terminal should resolve the problem, right? It doesn't though. If it was solving the issue, then I could have within the script you are recommending.

Comment: instead of psmouse, I actually had to target i2c_i801 to get the two finger scrolling to work again.

Comment: still there in ubuntu 20.04(focal)

Comment: On my lenovo x1 carbon, I had to replace `pmouse` with `i2c_i801` to get the 2 finger scrolling working after suspend.