# Touchpad stops working after System Restarts

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, touchpad, hp-touchpad

I am using HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15-ec-1xxx and I dual booted Ubuntu alongside my Windows. Coming to my problem, my touchpad doesn't work for long in the system.

After I installed Ubuntu 20.04, I have tried almost every code in terminal available on Youtube and surfed a lot of sites on Google and they do work but only before I shutfown my System. After I restart the System the next day, all I did on the previous day goes in vain.

Although the changes I made, the previous day, are present there but the touchpad doesn't work at all.

After all this, I reinstalled Ubuntu but this time, I chose normal installation + update software while installing + third party softwares, drives....

And after installation was complete, the touchpad did work, but again the next day, it was all same old. My touchpad stopped working again!

What should I do??

Comment: Did you try this solution here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083505/ubuntu-18-04-touchpad-not-fully-working-after-wake-from-suspend

Comment: It would be helpful if you could link all the ways you tried already. Otherwise we will advise, what you already tried.